# Facebook Sharing Button for Third Party Websites

Tags: facebook, button, share

I'm looking to create a way to share an activity done on a website in Facebook.  My particular interest is how to create a pop up frame that prompts the user to share their recent activity on facebook.  What is this called and how do I go about adding such code to a website?  An example is say someone donated money to a non-profit, how do you allow them to share the fact that they just donated on their facebook newsfeed with text and a custom image?

Answer (score 1):

It is called Send Dialog http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Thank you!  I'm pretty new to Facebook development so I'm sorry to be asking such basic questions.  How do I go about using this in a wordpress environment are there enclosing tags that I use when adding "send dialog"?